# Appropriate filesystem permission for apache2 + django(mod_wsgi) on OS X

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm getting tons and tons of the following in my apache error.log:

```
Current thread 0x00007fff730d2000 (most recent call first):
[Sat Apr 08 19:49:59.958559 2017] [core:notice] [pid 38953] AH00052: child pid 38968 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Sat Apr 08 19:49:59.960853 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 38969] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=38969): Unable to stat Python home /Users/user/Documents/VirtualEnvs/securedash. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I've tried countless filesystem permission and ownership combinations per the various suggestions found googling, but nothing has worked so far. I had this working about a week ago, via `chmod -R 777 ~/` which I don't want to do again. Upon realizing this was a bad idea, I repaired the permissions of my home directory and got distracted by something else. Now that I'm back working on it, I'm not able to run the app again. So what permissions does apache need for 1. My virtualenv and 2. The django project itself? Are there any other areas that I need to grant access to apache that I'm missing? Thanks!

**Edit** Reinstalled mod_wsgi and set up virtualenv from scratch:

```
$ which python3
    /usr/local/bin/python3

$ virtualenv -p python3 secureDash
    Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
    Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5'
    New python executable in /Users/user/Documents/VirtualEnvs/secureDash/bin/python3.5
    Also creating executable in /Users/user/Documents/VirtualEnvs/secureDash/bin/python
    Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

(secureDash) user VirtualEnvs $ python --version
    Python 3.5.2

(secureDash) user VirtualEnvs $ pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from /Users/user/Documents/VirtualEnvs/secureDash/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

$ ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3
    checking for apxs2... no
    checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking for prctl... no
    checking Apache version... 2.4.18
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating Makefile

$ make
    ./apxs -c -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  -Wc,'-arch x86_64' src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m  -arch x86_64 -lpython3.5 -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/mod_wsgi.lo src/server/mod_wsgi.c && touch src/server/mod_wsgi.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_apache.lo src/server/wsgi_apache.c && touch src/server/wsgi_apache.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_buckets.lo src/server/wsgi_buckets.c && touch src/server/wsgi_buckets.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_convert.lo src/server/wsgi_convert.c && touch src/server/wsgi_convert.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_daemon.lo src/server/wsgi_daemon.c && touch src/server/wsgi_daemon.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_interp.lo src/server/wsgi_interp.c && touch src/server/wsgi_interp.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_logger.lo src/server/wsgi_logger.c && touch src/server/wsgi_logger.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_memory.lo src/server/wsgi_memory.c && touch src/server/wsgi_memory.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_metrics.lo src/server/wsgi_metrics.c && touch src/server/wsgi_metrics.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_restrict.lo src/server/wsgi_restrict.c && touch src/server/wsgi_restrict.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_server.lo src/server/wsgi_server.c && touch src/server/wsgi_server.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_stream.lo src/server/wsgi_stream.c && touch src/server/wsgi_stream.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_thread.lo src/server/wsgi_thread.c && touch src/server/wsgi_thread.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -DDARWIN_10 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.Internal.sdk/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/wsgi_validate.lo src/server/wsgi_validate.c && touch src/server/wsgi_validate.slo
    ./libtool --silent --mode=link /usr/bin/cc    -o src/server/mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/libexec/apache2 -module -avoid-version    src/server/wsgi_validate.lo src/server/wsgi_thread.lo src/server/wsgi_stream.lo src/server/wsgi_server.lo src/server/wsgi_restrict.lo src/server/wsgi_metrics.lo src/server/wsgi_memory.lo src/server/wsgi_logger.lo src/server/wsgi_interp.lo src/server/wsgi_daemon.lo src/server/wsgi_convert.lo src/server/wsgi_buckets.lo src/server/wsgi_apache.lo src/server/mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m -arch x86_64 -lpython3.5 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation

$ sudo make install LIBEXECDIR=/usr/local/httpd/modules
Password:
    ./apxs -i -S LIBEXECDIR=/usr/local/httpd/modules -n 'mod_wsgi' src/server/mod_wsgi.la
    /usr/share/httpd/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='./libtool' src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/local/httpd/modules
    ./libtool --mode=install install src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/local/httpd/modules/
    libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.so /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
    libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.lai /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.la
    libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.a /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.a
    libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.a
    libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.a
    libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/libexec/apache2'
    chmod 755 /usr/local/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Comment: This is generally because you are trying to use a non standard Python installation and when building mod_wsgi it wasn't built correctly so it would find the alternate Python installation. Alternatively, can be because you are using a Python virtual environment built with a Python installation different to what mod_wsgi was built for. Include details about what Python installation you are using, how you built mod_wsgi and how you are configuring mod_wsgi in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: I added some additional details. I ran into python installation/mod_wsgi compilation issues when setting up my production server, so I was more careful when setting things up on my mac dev machine. All python versions should match across mod_wsgi compilation/and virtualenv. I've been leaning toward a filesystem issue since I had this working before I repaired the permissions on my home directory.

Comment: Whose Apache installation are you using? The Apache installation from Apple doesn't allow ``sudo make install`` to work. Why are you using an old mod_wsgi version? Is that a version of Python you built yourself or is it from Homebrew? And what do you get if you run ``otool -L mod_wsgi.so`` on the installed ``mod_wsgi.so`` file?

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally grabbed from my notes on how I compiled mod_wsgi on my production server (raspbian). Corrected above. I'm using the native apache installation my mac (OS X El Capitan). `$ otool -L mod_wsgi.so
mod_wsgi.so:
 /usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python (compatibility version 3.5.0, current version 3.5.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1259.0.0)`

Comment: As I asked, is that a version of Python you built yourself or is it from Homebrew, or even perhaps Anaconda Python? If you use Anaconda Python installation you will have issues because Anaconda Python distribution has broken the ability for it to be used in embedded systems like mod_wsgi. A workaround is necessary to use Anaconda Python distribution. Also, are you still use the old mod_wsgi version or not?

Comment: I installed python3 via Homebrew. Looks like I compiled mod_wsgi-4.5.9.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you aren't somehow using an older mod_wsgi version. This issue as it applied to Anaconda was supposed to have been fixed in mod_wsgi 4.5.7. I wouldn't be surprised if Homebrew Python somehow started having same issue as Anaconda Python. Can you please use latest, and alternate way of installing mod_wsgi. Namely, use ``pip install mod_wsgi`` and then run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` and use the output of that in place of what you have in Apache configuration file to load mod_wsgi. IOW, replace ``LoadModule`` etc with that output.

Comment: I can give that a try.

Comment: I haven't been able to follow your specific LoadModule steps, I did however recompile mod_wsgi with the latest version. Those steps are in the edit above. The unfortunate news is that I'm still getting the same error. I now believe that this issue is caused by the fact that the directory that my project is in (and apache points to) are a symlink to the iCloud directory on my mac. In addition to the reported error I also see now that I'm getting "AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /Users/user/icloud"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing my project from a symbolic-linked directory. As mentioned in my last comment above, I had my project in my iCloud directory so that it was easily accessible by all of my machines until I got the project up on github. To more easily access the iCloud directory,
I set up a symlink:

`~/icloud -> Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`

After a while I noticed the following error amongst the slew of the reported error above:

```
AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /Users/user/icloud
```

So once I got my project on github, I pulled it into `~/projects` and pointed my apache configuration in the right place and its working.

There may have been some other workaround to get apache to follow the symlink, but after some investigation, that seemed more difficult than moving my project to a regular directory that apache could follow.